# How do I use the voting rights associated with my U.S. shares?

Tags: united-states, shares

I have an account with a Swedish broker which provides access to several markets, including NASDAQ and NYSE markets in the United States. On the broker's website, it says how to vote at the annual general meeting when I hold shares in a Swedish company. On the record date, the broker submits a list of all shareholers to the Swedish company. No later than the record date, I tell the company that I wish to attend the meeting. The company will then send me an entry card which I present at the meeting.

If I buy foreign (that is, non-Swedish) shares, the procedure seems to be different. I have held a position in a U.S. company since 2009. I presumably missed the record date for the 2009 meeting, but I definitely held that position on the record dates during the following years. However, I can't figure out how to use my voting rights. United States companies seem to provide online voting through certain websites such as http://www.proxyvote.com/ and http://www.voteproxy.com/ making voting viable (a flight to the United States costs too much and takes too much time, so attending the meeting in person is not an option). However, the voting websites require some kind of login credentials (a so-called control number), and I don't know which website I should use. How do I obtain those login credentials, and how do I find out which website I should use? The website suggests that my broker should provide that information, but my broker does not, at least not by default.

So: How do I exercise my voting rights for my U.S. shares?

Answer (score 3):

If your shares are held in "street name" by your broker (which is the more likely case) - then your broker should provide you the information on how and when to vote. If you hold the shares in your own name, make sure the company knows your address and you'll get the proxy statement and the voting instructions mailed to you.

Talk to your broker about it.